# Figuring out the biggest array I can create in memory

Tags: java, memory, runtime

I am sorting a number of integers from a file, which will probably be too large to fit into memory in one go, my current idea is to get sort chucks with quicksort, then mergesort them together. I would like to make the chunks as big as possible, so I'd like to know how much I can read in in one go.

I know about Runtime.FreeMemory, but how should I go about using it. Should I carefully work out what other variables I use in the program then create an array of size (freeMemory - variablesSizes), or is that too likely to go wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: There are so called "external sorting algorithms". They are designed to sort data which does not fit into ram. See Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting

Comment: Any hint as to approximately HOW many integers?  1 million, 1 billion, ...1 trillion?

Comment: I'll take "What is premature optimization?" for 1000, Alex.

Comment: What kind of performance expectations do you have, and how many ints do you have? A simple test app I wrote can sort 100,000,000 ints (a 1.1Gb text file) in 9min with a chunk size of 1,000,000, 5min with a chunk size of 10,000,000, 2.5 min with a chunk size of 50,000,000 and 80sec with a chunk size of 100,000,000 (ie no merging of chunks required, just load the whole thing into memory and sort). Note I had to use -Xmx1024M for the last test. The actual in memory sort only took 17s, the rest of the time was IO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experiment until you find a size that works well. The largest array you can allocate on the heap isn't necessarily the fastest way to do it. In many circumstances, the entire heap does not fit in the computers RAM, and might be swapped out in parts. Just because you can allocate a huge array, does not mean it will be the best size for optimizing speed.

Some adaptive approach would probably be best (testing number of items sorted/second depending on array size) and adjusting for what you can fit without getting an OutOfMemoryError.

Simpler: stick with some large value that works well, but isn't necessarily the largest you can use.

Or: use an external library/database to do what you want - working with huge amounts of data is tricky to get right in general, and you will probably get better performance and shorter development time if you don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with a relatively small chunk size for the first chunk. Then I'd double the chunk for every next chunk until you get an OutOfMemoryException. Though that will probably trigger swapping.

Answer (score 0):

I think figuring out **exactly** how much memory we can allocate is a sticky buisness, as by default in java the jvm will allocate a heap space of 256M, but this can always be increated using -Xmx, so it is best to trade performace for portability by having a fixed chunk size of lets say around 150M.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with java building sorting functionality, you will have to use a Collection of some sort, which will not take int primitive types, but rather, you will have to use Integer objects. (`List<Integer>`)

In my experiences (not to be taken as gospel), an int weighs in at (obviously) 4 bytes of ram, whereas an Integer weighs in at 12 bytes on a 32bit machine and 24 bytes on a 64bit machine.

If you need to minimize memory foot print, use int[] and then implement your own sorter...
However, it might be easier all the way around to use `List<Integer>`, and the built in sorting functions and just deal with having to have more of smaller sized Lists.

To answer the question though, you should definitely look at the Merge-Sort angle of attack to this problem and just pick an arbitrary List size to start with.  You will likely find, after some experimentation, that there is a trade off between list size and number of chunks.  Find the sweet spot and tell us your results!

Comment: [`Arrays.sort(int[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int[]%29) works with primitive arrays. It also uses an in-place quicksort, so there's basically no space overhead.

Comment: Awesome, I keep forgetting about Arrays class :)  Thanks!